# How to run an attribute value through a regular expression after extracting via BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, regex, url, unicode, beautifulsoup

I have a URL that I want to parse a part of, particularly the widgetid:

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com/process.asp?widgetid=4530">Widgets Rock!</a>
```

I've written this Python (I'm a bit of a newbie at Python -- version is 2.7):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = open('c:\Python27\some_xml_file.txt')
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)


links = soup.findAll('a')

# debugging statements

print type(links[7])
# output: <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>

print links[7]
# output: <a href="http://www.somesite.com/process.asp?widgetid=4530">Widgets Rock!</a>

theURL = links[7].attrs['href']
print theURL
# output: http://www.somesite.com/process.asp?widgetid=4530

print type(theURL)
# output: <type 'unicode'>

is_widget_url = re.compile('[0-9]')
print is_widget_url.match(theURL)
# output: None (I know this isn't the correct regex but I'd think it
#         would match if there's any number in there!)
```

I think I'm missing something with the regular expression (or my understanding of how to use them) but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The reason `urlparse` is being suggested is that it already has the query string parsing logic worked out -- so for instance if you ever get a URL with more parameters it will still work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question doesn't have anything to do with BeautifulSoup.

The problem is that, as [the documentation explains](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match), `match` only matches at the beginning of the string. Since the digits you want to find are at the end of the string, it returns nothing.

To match on a digit anywhere, use `search` - and you probably want to use the `\d` entity for digits.

```
matches = re.search(r'\d+', theURL)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That stumped me for quite a while!

Comment: Don't use `re` for this, use `urlparse`.

Comment: @Tichodroma, is this because of efficiency (using urlparse rather than regex)?

Comment: No, because Python comes [with batteries included](http://www.python.org/about/).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you want an re - it's possible you want:

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
s = 'http://www.somesite.com/process.asp?widgetid=4530'
qs = parse_qs(urlparse(s).query)
if 'widgetid' in qs:
   # it's got a widget, a widget it has got...
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I guess regex is my favorite parsing hammer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse):

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
o = urlparse("http://www.somesite.com/process.asp?widgetid=4530")
if "widgetId" in parse_qs(o.query):
    # this is a 'widget URL'
```